# monty hall question with 4 doors

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Explain the Monty Hall problem in the case of 4 doors computing specific probabilities.

I got that you have 1/4 chance of picking the door with the goat.
1/4 chance to pick the door with the prize and so on.

if I pick an empty door you have a 1/2 chance of doing this in this case you have 1/2 chance of winning the prize. if you don't switch

if you don't switch your chance is 1/4

switching is better

I think Im  missing something

Comment: initially, you have 1/4 chance of picking the prize, and 3/4 chance of not picking the prize. When the host opens all doors but two, you have two options: ur initial 1/4 chance, or switching for a 3/4 chance. The only reason switching is better is because the host has already gotten rid of 2 empty doors

Comment: I think the key to "intuiting" this problem is to remember that your initial choice is perfectly random, but Monty's choices are not random at all, i.e. there is no way he is going to open the door hiding the prize.  Now, keep that in mind and ask yourself: what if there are 1000 doors?  You pick one, then Monty opens up 998 of them.  Do you switch or not?  Think about it: The chance that you picked the right door initially is 1/1000.  The chance that Monty was going to open the right door is exactly zero.

Comment: In the Monty Hall problem, instead of picking the door with the prize, you can instead imagine you have to correctly pick one of the $n - 1$ doors without prize to win. By always changing at the end, that is effectively what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I assume there are 4 doors - 3 with goats and a single one with the prize:

FIRST CASE: Show host opens 2 doors for you:

If you had picked the right door to begin with, you would lose from changing. However, this will only be the case 1/4 of the time. So 1/4 of the time you will win by staying.

Then show opens two doors with goats -

3/4 of the time, you will be at a goat to begin with, but the showing of two goat makes it so that the remaining one (if you are on a goat) is the prize. Now since 3/4 of the time you will be on a goat - 3/4 of the time you will win by changing.

SECOND CASE: Show host opens just 1 door for you:

If you had picked the right door to begin with, you would lose from changing. However, this will only be the case 1/4 of the time. So 1/4 of the time you will win by staying.

Then show opens a door with a goat -

3/4 of the time, you will choose a door with a goat to begin with. The revealing of a goat makes it so that 3/4 of the time the remaining 2 doors must hold the prize! But wait, now it's down to pure luck, good old 50/50. So your chance of winning in this case will be (3/4) * (1/2) or 3/8.

So overall your three options: there is a 2/8 (1/4) chance of winning by not changing, a 3/8 chance of losing by changing (moving to lets say door x) and a 3/8 chance of winning from changing (lets say moving to door y). The sum is fortunately =1.

Cheers!

Comment: This is OK until the paragraph with the "three options." There are two strategies, each of which has two possible outcomes; for each strategy, the sum of the probabilities its _two_ outcomes is $1.$ This answer is adding three numbers which are supposedly one outcome of one strategy and two outcomes of the other (and one of those probabilities is incorrect--you have a $\frac58$ chance of losing if you change).

Comment: What you _can_ correctly say is that _if you change,_ you have a $\frac38$ chance to win, a $\frac14$ chance to lose because the car is behind the door you chose the first time, and a $\frac38$ chance to lose because the car is behind the one remaining door that you never chose.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2 doors are open after first pick:

With the non-switching strategy:

You need to pick the right door from the start with probability $\frac{1}{4}$

with the switching strategy:

You need to pick a non-correct door at first with probability $\frac{3}{4}$

After that ther are two doors remaining, the one you picked first (wrong) and the one unpicked remaining (the winner) so after switching you have the winning one.

So probability with switching is $\frac{3}{4}>\frac{1}{4}$, so you should switch.

Comment: the probability isn't halved if you switch - should be the full 3/4

Comment: Does he open all doors or only 1 after the first choice?

Comment: Think about it this way: When there are two doors left, the only way that switching would cause him to lose is if he picked the right door in the first place - a 1/4 chance. Thus, his chance of winning when switching is 3/4 (or 1 - 1/4)

Comment: It is possible he got it wrong in the first place, then chose the wrong one when he has to make the choice between the 2 remaining.

Comment: the chance he got it wrong in the first place is 1/4... no matter how many door the host opens, the chances stay at 1/4. Since probabilities must add up to one, the other remaining door must contain 3/4 chance.

Comment: Ok, here is how I think it works: you pick door, then he says wanna switch, and opens an empty door. and you get 1 last chance to pick or stay.

Comment: yes, that is how it works. he will give you the chance to switch after opening all but two doors, yours and a random one. however, notice that your door's chance doesn't increase as he eliminates empty doors one by one - it stays at a constant 1/4. Thus, the remaining 3/4 chance must be in the other door

Comment: Oh, that's what I asked in second comment, I am assuming he only opens 1 door. Clearly if he opens 2 then it is only 3/4.

Answer (score 0):

***Using Bayes' Theorem***
**Ist Case**
Probability of the door with prize behind it = 1/4
probability of the other three door without prize = 3/4
**2nd Case**
(1)**without switching**
Probability of you winning=(1/4)*(1) + (3/4)*(0) = 1/4
(2).**With Switching**
Probability of you winning=(1/4)*(0)+(3/4)*(1/2)=3/8

Answer (score 0):

P(Winning | You did not switch) = P(choosing the right door at the first go).

Hence, the probability of winning if by not switching = 1/4.

P(Winning | You switched ) = P( choosing incorrect door out of 4 doors)* P(choosing the correct door out of two doors, remaining after host opens one door)

Hence, P(Winning| You switched) = 3/4 * 1/2 = 3/8.

Answer (score -1):

First part of experiment:

- probability of wining gift is $.25$.

2nd part of experiment:

- without switching the probability of prize is $.25$
- with switching the probability of wining the prize is $.75 \times .5 = .375$, which is greater as compared to without switching case.