# Monty Hall with 4 Doors Solution

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I am trying to analyze a Monty Hall question with four doors (3 goats, 1  car) just so I can then apply the problem with n doors.

I applied Bayes' theorem, calculated the probabilities and am trying to do an expected value analysis. In order to do so, I am looking at every option a player of the game has but when I add up the probabilities, it gets a result greater than 1.

What I have so far (assuming only one goat is revealed):

You have a 1/4 chance of winning without switching, 3/8 if you win and switch, 3/8 if you lose after switching. I confirmed this answer with @Just_a_fool response [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682586/monty-hall-question-with-4-doors?answertab=votes#tab-top). However, shouldn't Just_a_fool also take in consideration the change of losing without switching (3/4 chance) in order to get every outcome? The problem with that is the probability adds up to 1.75. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you missed (and at least three other people also missed, judging from the upvotes) is that the explanation of the sum $\frac14+\frac38+\frac38$ in that answer is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) will help decide who is right or if all are wrong so far. It does talk about having a million doors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the chance of not getting the price when switching is $\frac{5}{8}$, rather than $\frac{3}{8}$, since there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance the price is behind the door you chose initially, and there is a $\frac{3}{8}$ chance that it is the other of the two doors that you pick from when switching, so $P(Lose|Switch)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{5}{8}$

As such, you have that $P(Win|Switch)=\frac{3}{8}$, and $P(Lose|Switch)=\frac{5}{8}$, which adds up to $1$ ... as it should: when you switch, you either win or lose!

You also have that $P(Lose|Stay)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $P(Win|Stay)=\frac{1}{4}$, which also adds up to $1$ .. as it should: when you stay, you either win or lose!

But you are adding up $P(Win|Switch)+P(Lose|Switch)+P(Lose|Stay)+P(Win|Stay)$ ... and are surprised that this is greater than $1$ ....

Well, you shouldn't, because that should add up to $2$, not $1$. And, as we saw already, you got $1.75$ because you didn't get $P(Lose|Switch)$ correct.

Comment: The key point for OP to understand (not really about Monty Hall, but about probability in general) is that it doesn't really mean anything to sum up conditional probabilities under different conditions. (I am aware that $P(A \mid B) P(B) + P(A \mid B^c) P(B^c)$ for instance means something, but that's really only because it is the same thing as $P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)$.)

Comment: So if I were to calculate the expected value where the discrete variable is let's say winning 1 dollar from the prize door and losing nothing from the goat doors but the player bet 1 dollar, would E(x)=0? Also thank you @Ian for telling me that that, I am in a very basic probability course that hasn't taught me yet

Comment: @JDog I think the answer hinges on whether or not they always show  you and then remove a losing door after you switch. If they do, then my answer makes more sense; if not, then Bram28 makes more sense.

Comment: @poetasis My answers assumes that the host *always* show a losing door, and that the host picks that one with equal probability from all the losing doors other than the pone you initially picked.

Comment: @poetasis The whole point of Monty Hall is that the host never shows a winning door. If they can ever show you a winning door, then even when they *do* show you a losing door, there is still no advantage to switching.

Comment: @Ian Mythbusters tested the Monty Hall thing with paper mock-ups and after a hundred or so trials, it confirmed that switching increases your chances of winning in the real world. It's a paradox, yet it's real.

Comment: @poetasis I think you missed my point. There isn't really a paradox, the entire discrepancy is based on the the rule that they can't open the winning door. Suppose they can open the winning door and you automatically lose in that case. Then, without switching, of course you still have a 1/3 shot. With switching, there's a 2/3 chance that you guess wrong, followed by only a 1/2 chance of winning. And if you guess right and switch then of course you lose. So the odds are the same. (The situation is a bit different with 4 doors and 1 winning door, however.)